# Why is the transactionsRoot the same hash as "empty patricia merkle trie" root hash?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, merkle-patricia-tries

My setup is as follows: I am Using ganache-cli and metamask to send 1 ETH from account 1 to account 2.

When I use JsonRPC to get the Information about Block 1 (the one with the transaction) the Result is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "number": "0x1",
        "hash": "0x632aaef1f8064ac21f397e4df019265ec840407890dcefe8886b4437bf558bf3",
        "parentHash": "0xcbf6f09b269f9301117f5bf23a2f2b0774607ce4355f24b9d01dda084c100e38",
        "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
        "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
        "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "transactionsRoot": "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
        "stateRoot": "0xe6f3c88a8d790bab7c736fec7d69fe535d817ccd03c5f5f6095928cfb2c491d4",
        "receiptsRoot": "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
        "miner": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "difficulty": "0x0",
        "totalDifficulty": "0x0",
        "extraData": "0x",
        "size": "0x03e8",
        "gasLimit": "0x6691b7",
        "gasUsed": "0x5208",
        "timestamp": "0x5b7e6a8b",
        "transactions": [
            {
                "hash": "0x2f46e991a2e12640dd6743ed47ac824175fda87fa0307af4fdd1b144bdc1463e",
                "nonce": "0x0",
                "blockHash": "0x632aaef1f8064ac21f397e4df019265ec840407890dcefe8886b4437bf558bf3",
                "blockNumber": "0x01",
                "transactionIndex": "0x00",
                "from": "0xf5ba0f0c83a8d919690edc025c6e14264bf3b40d",
                "to": "0x1c63e4448f37d4cdf4e50d513ef8f6e934e6109e",
                "value": "0x0de0b6b3a7640000",
                "gas": "0x7b0c",
                "gasPrice": "0x3b9aca00",
                "input": "0x0",
                "v": "0x02cacb9dc96d",
                "r": "0x3f89d286621738d221f5ed58774278731457b2c4c42357972e80d629d55ca240",
                "s": "0x31305c70b88b0f57f359fed89017539a1d92a6b5fc382a3372ad1d9190acc499"
            }
        ],
        "uncles": []
    }
}
```

Why is transactionsRoot == receiptsRoot == "root of an empty trie"?
I can clearly see that there is a Transaction in the Block. Shouldn't the root then be different?

Thanks in advance.